# window.open and window.location does not work

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am trying to use userscript to simulate click on appearing notification.

Greasemonkey script [checkForBadJavascripts](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2620135) that replaces orginial JS code of notification with modified code.

Part of original code is

```
onClickHandler = function() {
  var win = window.open(data.url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
};

var notification = $.notification(options);
```

Modified code is

```
 onClickHandler = function() {
  console.log("click!");
  var win = window.open(data.url, '_blank');
  win.focus();

};
  var notification = $.notification(options);
  onClickHandler();
```

The code is succesfully substituted, and when notification appears onClickHandler is executed, and I can see "click!" in my console. However, new window is not opened. I have also tried the following code.

```
 var notification = $.notification(options);
 console.log("click!");
 window.location.href = "http://google.com";
```

I can still see "click!" in console every time notification appears, but for some reason trying to open google does nothing.

When I type

```
window.location.href = "http://google.com";
```

directly into the console, it is executed without any problems.
What is the reason for this and how to make it work?

Comment: `window.location.href` is not a function. Just change it to `window.location.href = data.url`
Also make sure your window isn't being blocked by any popup plugin you've got installed in your browser.

Comment: @mengstrom my bad, there is no window.location.href(data.url) in my real script, I tried doing that, but it did nothing, and I forgot to remove it

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, `windows.location.href`is not a function.

Also, in the code provided you aren't passing anything into your `onClickHandler` so where is this `data`-object?

Given the code provided, take a look at this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/U67vpYv0staYpf8Gnuwc?p=preview) or down below.

```
onClickHandler = function(data) {
  console.log("click!");
  var win = window.open(data.url);
  win.location.href = data.url; // you could skip this
  win.focus(); // I belive this could also be skipped

};

onClickHandler({url: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'});
```

Besides, there's no need to use `windows.location.href`since you are already providing the url in  `window.open()`.

> In my browser (Chrome) I have a plugin that blocks popups so in the event that you also do, you should see the window being blocked to the far right up in your location bar.